# Apache VirtualHost setup for client / server on same AWS instance

Tags: apache, virtualhost

I am trying to setup a ReactJS front end and Wordpress back end on the same AWS instance without a domain name. The AWS instance is running Amazon Linux.

I am attempting to use an IP address and port numbers to map to the Apache virtual hosts. I added the following VirtualHost directives to the httpd.conf file. Where the IP has been replaced with 1.1.1.1

```
ServerRoot "/etc/httpd"

Listen 80
Listen 8080

Include conf.modules.d/*.conf

User webapp
Group webapp

ServerAdmin root@localhost
ServerName localhost

<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>

DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/"

<Directory "/var/www">
    AllowOverride All
    # Allow open access:
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<VirtualHost 1.1.1.1:80>
    ServerName 1.1.1.1
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/client/public_html
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 1.1.1.1:8080>
    ServerName 1.1.1.1
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/server/public_html
</VirtualHost>
```

However when I try and access the site it is still directing all traffic to`/var/www/html/`regardless of whether I try and access port 80 or 8080

Comment: "Connection refused" usually means that Apache isn't running.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I messed up the configuration of the main config file which must have caused apache to crash. I have updated the question with the httpd.conf file I now have in place. I can't seem to get the redirect to work

Comment: You have a stray DocumentRoot which will cause issues, look above `<Directory "/var/www">`.

Comment: @SimonHayter Why would that `DocumentRoot` directive "cause issues"? That directive looks like it's defining the default `DocumentRoot` in the main server config (for `localhost`) and is most probably required. Any `VirtualHosts` that match would simply override this.

Comment: Well, because its not contained you are having it override all the other virtual hosts. Furthermore, when using `<VirtualHost 1.1.1.1:8080>` you shouldn't need to use `ServerName 1.1.1.1` because it is already listening on the IP address and only when using a domain should you need to use the ServerName or ServerAlias. If you used `<VirtualHost *:80>` then you could use ServerName to be more specific.

Comment: But also, you should try `NameVirtualHost 1.1.1.1:80` after `Listen 80`. I'd also recommend that you put the directory directives in the virtual host, currently you have 3 different directories under the default. So one for the default, one each for the virtual hosts.

Comment: What files are being included with `conf.modules.d/*.conf`?

Comment: @SimonHayter I tried removing the default DocumentRoot directive and I got `Forbidden: You don't have permission to access / on this server.` I also tried adding the directory directives to the Virtual host and added the NameVirtualHost but the issue remains. I just seems like none of the VirtualHost directives are taking any effect

Comment: @DocRoot Looking at the directory listing for `conf.modules.d/` it appears to be loading the following conf files: `00-base.conf, 00-mpm.conf, 00-proxy.conf, 00-optional.conf, 15-php.conf -> /etc/alternatives/15-php.conf` There are a few other files in that dir but they dont have that extension

Comment: You need to examine those additional config files. The reason for your "errors" would seem to be that the `<VirtualHost>` is simply not matching... either because you have the wrong server IP address, or because another `<VirtualHost>` is taking priority? What version of Apache are you using?

Comment: The purpose of `ServerName` is to give the name of the website in the configuration, so you should not put an IP address there.